# Is it possible to instruct libmysqld (embedded MySql DB engine) to work with an in-memory database?

Tags: mysql, in-memory-database

I have a zip archive with MySQL database files in it. I successfully read the database with libmysqld after I unzip the archive contents.

My question is this - does libmysqld understand the notion of an in-memory database? I could have extracted my zip archive into some memory structure and then had libmysqld work with it, instead of the files on disk. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up a table with storage engine = RAM. In fact, as I understand it, MySQL generally chooses RAM if it can: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html . But, in my experience, you have to tell mySQL to copy a disk-resident table to a RAM table. That is, I've never been able to do what you might want: to bring the database into RAM from disk and then point MySQL at it and expect MySQL to understand it: for example, I don't believe that MySQL can grok an IDX file that used to be on disk and is now in RAM.

**EDIT:** You can create and copy the disk-resident table into the RAM table in one MySQL operation. The operation is:

CREATE TABLE Ramtable SELECT * FROM Disktable (Don't have to worry about capitalization: MySQL is case-agnostic wrt operations/requests.)

The description of the operation is here: http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_copy_table.php .

I'm too lazy to edit my C-language code and post it, but it is super-simple. Just spend 15 or 20 mins reading the docs and you'll get it right away.

Comment: Yes, you do understand it. My desired flow is: ZIP file -> RAM -> MySQL

Comment: Then, according to me your flow must be: MySQL(copy ZIP-file table to RAM table) -> MySQL (normal operation on RAM table). Now I think about it, though, that could be a plus because it avoids your original copy-to-RAM operation: MySQL does the copy for you; and MySQL copy table is very quick. MySQL is highly optimized to do that kind of thing.

Comment: I think you are overestimating my MySQL mileage. Could you give me a few lines of code that sketches how to do this `MySQL(copy ZIP-file table to RAM table) -> MySQL (normal operation on RAM table)` ?

Comment: I understand your suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not save me much, because I still have to extract the archive contents to disk. Selecting into the memory table does not make much sense to me, since I am doing one pass on the data anyway. If I could avoid archive extraction to the disk - that could be a different story.